# Insert a variable at line #1 of txt file using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ["$#" -ne "1"]; then
   echo "Usage: `basename $0` <HOSTNAME>"
   exit 1
fi

IPADDR=`ifconfig | head -2 | tail -1 | cut -d: -f2 | rev | cut -c8-23 | rev`
sed -i -e '1i$IPADDR   $1\' /etc/hosts
```

But when I `cat /etc/hosts`:

```
$IPADDR
```

How can I deal with such issues?

Comment: There are more reliable ways of extracting the ip address, see for example [Putting IP Address into bash variable. Is there a better way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6829605/1331399).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that variables inside single quotes `'` aren't expanded by the shell, but left unchanged. To quote variables you want expanded use double quotes `"` or just leave off the quotes if they are unneeded like here, e.g.

```
sed -i -e '1i'$IPADDR'   '$1'\' /etc/hosts
```

In above line `$IPADDR` and `$1` are outside of quotes and will be expanded by the shell before the arguments are being feed to `sed`.

Comment: You know I have also `$1` as argument... how about it?

Comment: @MortezaLSC: Same pattern, keep them outside of single quotes, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

The single quotes mean the string isn't interpolated as a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
IPADDR=$(/sbin/ifconfig | head -2 | tail -1 | cut -d: -f2 | rev | cut -c8-23 | rev)
sed -i -e "1i${IPADDR}   ${1}" /etc/hosts
```

I also did the command in `$(...)` out of habit!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to sed manual:https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

> As a GNU extension, the i command and text can be separated into two
> -e parameters, enabling easier scripting:

The formal usage should be:

> `sed -i -e "1i$IPADDR\\" -e "$1" /etc/hosts`