# Find and replace using sed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am trying to replace  this command:

```
HOST_IP_ADDRESS=$(/sbin/ifconfig  | grep inet | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d)
```

in my multipile script file in a single try. I greped the output through

```
 grep -R 'HOST_IP_ADDRESS' ./ -R | grep "127.0.0.1" | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'
```

I want to replace the result with HOST_IP_ADDRESS=`hostname -i` instead of

```
HOST_IP_ADDRESS=$(/sbin/ifconfig  | grep inet | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d
```

is their any way do this through sed command.

Comment: As I already mentioned in the linked question, please be aware that 
all the `hostname` tips/answers will most likely fail on anything else than **GNU's** `hostname` implementation, as on almost all other flavors of Unix this tool is meant to **set** the hostname instead of looking up funny things. To my knowledge, this includes OSX, *BSD, Solaris and probably a lot more. So relying on this behavior will result in non-portable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will edit your files in-place, replacing the ifconfig hack with `$(hostname -i)`:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(HOST_IP_ADDRESS=\).*/\1$(hostname -i)/' filenames-go-here
```

Make backups first.

Actually it will not just replace the ifconfig hack, it will replace any lines beginning with `HOST_IP_ADDRESS=`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use sed? Maybe you could use this alternative solution:

```
HOST_IP_ADDRESS=$(hostname -I | cut -f1 -d' ')
```

See [Putting IP Address into bash variable. Is there a better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829605/putting-ip-address-into-bash-variable-is-there-a-better-way)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well you want to replace this:

```
HOST_IP_ADDRESS=$(/sbin/ifconfig  | grep inet | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d)
```

by:

```
HOST_IP_ADDRESS=$(hostname -i)
```

Which is a bit hard because of the characters that need to be escaped, take a look at the script below:

```
#! /bin/bash

o='HOST_IP_ADDRESS=$(/sbin/ifconfig  | grep inet | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '\''{print $2}'\'' | cut -d)'
n='HOST_IP_ADDRESS=$(hostname -i)'

echo "$o" > file
sed -e 's#'"$o"'#'"$n"'#g' file
```

Its output:

```
bash  test.sh 
HOST_IP_ADDRESS=$(hostname -i)

cat file
HOST_IP_ADDRESS=$(/sbin/ifconfig  | grep inet | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d)
```

It's all about how you escape things, as you can see this script creates a file containing the old string in `$o` then it replaces by the new string `$n`, if you want to modify the file use `-i.bak` instead of `-e` for sed  to ensure you make a backup